# Get account's installed android apps through SDK with oAuth authorization

Tags: android, ios, oauth, sdk

is possible to get google account's installed apps programmatically (play market-> my apps) (from ios with ouath)? 
I looked at google apis and did not found something suitable.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking about Google's server apis, not Android's apis?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yes, from iOS device with oAuth (or g+) authentication.

Comment: @petey yes, from iOs device.